# Initializing plog::RollingFileAppender on Windows XP Triggers Access Violation (Null Pointer)

Tags: c++, access-violation

When using [plog][1] on Windows XP. In this case, the code is:

```
void LogInit(void)
{   
    static plog::RollingFileAppender<plog::TxtFormatter> fileAppender("log.log");
```

Using Visual Studio 2019 but the project uses the platform toolset Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_XP)

The output assembly is:

```
;   COMDAT _LogInit
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_status$1$ = -516                   ; size = 4
_appender$66 = -516                 ; size = 4
$T65 = -512                     ; size = 256
$T64 = -512                     ; size = 256
$T62 = -512                     ; size = 256
$T60 = -512                     ; size = 256
$T58 = -256                     ; size = 256
$T57 = -256                     ; size = 256
$T41 = -256                     ; size = 256
_LogInit PROC                       ; COMDAT

; 108  : {  

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 83 e4 f8     and     esp, -8            ; fffffff8H

; 109  :    static plog::RollingFileAppender<plog::TxtFormatter> fileAppender("log.log");

  00006 64 a1 00 00 00
    00       mov     eax, DWORD PTR fs:__tls_array
  0000c 81 ec 04 02 00
    00       sub     esp, 516       ; 00000204H
  00012 8b 0d 00 00 00
    00       mov     ecx, DWORD PTR __tls_index
  00018 53       push    ebx
  00019 56       push    esi
  0001a 8b 34 88     mov     esi, DWORD PTR [eax+ecx*4]
```

The null pointer is because EAX (__tls_array) and ECX (__tls_index) area both null. Output from WinDbg:

```
TGLOBALFLAG:  70

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=7c90e4f4 esi=0012f624 edi=00000000
eip=1000366a esp=001afda4 ebp=001affb4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010216
LogTest!LogInit+0x1a:
1000366a 8b3488          mov     esi,dword ptr [eax+ecx*4] ds:0023:00000000=????????
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 1000366a (LogTest!LogInit+0x0000001a)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
Attempt to read from address 00000000

PROCESS_NAME:  notepad.exe

READ_ADDRESS:  00000000 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

FAULTING_LOCAL_VARIABLE_NAME:  fileAppender

STACK_TEXT:  
001affb4 7c80b713     00000000 00000000 0012f624 LogTest!LogInit+0x1a
001affec 00000000     10003650 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37


STACK_COMMAND:  ~1s; .ecxr ; kb

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  d:\test\logtest.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  d:\test\logtest.cpp

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  109

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
   105: 
   106: // This is an example of an exported function.
   107: LogInit_API void LogInit(void)
   108: {   
>  109:     static plog::RollingFileAppender<plog::TxtFormatter> fileAppender(";pg.log");
   110:     plog::init(plog::info, &fileAppender);
   111:     
   112: 
   113:     
   114: 


SYMBOL_NAME:  LogTest!LogInit+1a

MODULE_NAME: LogTest

IMAGE_NAME:  LogTest.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_LogTest.dll!LogInit

OS_VERSION:  5.1.2600.5512

BUILDLAB_STR:  xpsp

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows XP

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {0218fa42-bce4-328f-5683-a7e3657927fc}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Code for affected class is:

```
namespace plog
{
    template<class Formatter, class Converter = NativeEOLConverter<UTF8Converter> >
    class PLOG_LINKAGE_HIDDEN RollingFileAppender : public IAppender
    {
    public:
        RollingFileAppender(const util::nchar* fileName, size_t maxFileSize = 0, int maxFiles = 0)
            : m_fileSize()
            , m_maxFileSize()
            , m_maxFiles(maxFiles)
            , m_firstWrite(true)
        {
            setFileName(fileName);
            setMaxFileSize(maxFileSize);
        }

#ifdef _WIN32
        RollingFileAppender(const char* fileName, size_t maxFileSize = 0, int maxFiles = 0)
            : m_fileSize()
            , m_maxFileSize()
            , m_maxFiles(maxFiles)
            , m_firstWrite(true)
        {
            setFileName(fileName);
            setMaxFileSize(maxFileSize);
        }
#endif

        virtual void write(const Record& record)
        {
            util::MutexLock lock(m_mutex);

            if (m_firstWrite)
            {
                openLogFile();
                m_firstWrite = false;
            }
            else if (m_maxFiles > 0 && m_fileSize > m_maxFileSize && static_cast<size_t>(-1) != m_fileSize)
            {
                rollLogFiles();
            }

            size_t bytesWritten = m_file.write(Converter::convert(Formatter::format(record)));

            if (static_cast<size_t>(-1) != bytesWritten)
            {
                m_fileSize += bytesWritten;
            }
        }

        void setFileName(const util::nchar* fileName)
        {
            util::MutexLock lock(m_mutex);

            util::splitFileName(fileName, m_fileNameNoExt, m_fileExt);

            m_file.close();
            m_firstWrite = true;
        }

#ifdef _WIN32
        void setFileName(const char* fileName)
        {
            setFileName(util::toWide(fileName).c_str());
        }
#endif

        void setMaxFiles(int maxFiles)
        {
            m_maxFiles = maxFiles;
        }

        void setMaxFileSize(size_t maxFileSize)
        {
            m_maxFileSize = (std::max)(maxFileSize, static_cast<size_t>(1000)); // set a lower limit for the maxFileSize
        }

        void rollLogFiles()
        {
            m_file.close();

            util::nstring lastFileName = buildFileName(m_maxFiles - 1);
            util::File::unlink(lastFileName.c_str());

            for (int fileNumber = m_maxFiles - 2; fileNumber >= 0; --fileNumber)
            {
                util::nstring currentFileName = buildFileName(fileNumber);
                util::nstring nextFileName = buildFileName(fileNumber + 1);

                util::File::rename(currentFileName.c_str(), nextFileName.c_str());
            }

            openLogFile();
            m_firstWrite = false;
        }

    private:
        void openLogFile()
        {
            util::nstring fileName = buildFileName();
            m_fileSize = m_file.open(fileName.c_str());

            if (0 == m_fileSize)
            {
                size_t bytesWritten = m_file.write(Converter::header(Formatter::header()));

                if (static_cast<size_t>(-1) != bytesWritten)
                {
                    m_fileSize += bytesWritten;
                }
            }
        }

        util::nstring buildFileName(int fileNumber = 0)
        {
            util::nostringstream ss;
            ss << m_fileNameNoExt;

            if (fileNumber > 0)
            {
                ss << '.' << fileNumber;
            }

            if (!m_fileExt.empty())
            {
                ss << '.' << m_fileExt;
            }

            return ss.str();
        }

    private:
        util::Mutex     m_mutex;
        util::File      m_file;
        size_t          m_fileSize;
        size_t          m_maxFileSize;
        int             m_maxFiles;
        util::nstring   m_fileExt;
        util::nstring   m_fileNameNoExt;
        bool            m_firstWrite;
    };
}
```

Is there code or compiler settings that can be modified to fix/remove the references to __tls_array / __tls_index.
This occurs in both debug & release builds.
[1]: https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/plog

Answer (score 0):

Setting compiler option /Zc:threadSafeInit- removes the references to __tls_array and __tls_index and stops the access violation crash.

Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization?view=msvc-170) mentions:

> In the C++11 standard, block scope variables with static or thread
> storage duration must be zero-initialized before any other
> initialization takes place. Initialization occurs when control first
> passes through the declaration of the variable. If an exception is
> thrown during initialization, the variable is considered
> uninitialized, and initialization is re-attempted the next time
> control passes through the declaration. If control enters the
> declaration concurrently with initialization, the concurrent execution
> blocks while initialization is completed. The behavior is undefined if
> control re-enters the declaration recursively during initialization.
> By default, Visual Studio starting in Visual Studio 2015 implements
> this standard behavior. This behavior may be explicitly specified by
> setting the /Zc:threadSafeInit compiler option.
>
> The /Zc:threadSafeInit compiler option is on by default. The
> /permissive- option does not affect /Zc:threadSafeInit.
>
> Thread-safe initialization of static local variables relies on code
> implemented in the Universal C run-time library (UCRT). To avoid
> taking a dependency on the UCRT, or to preserve the non-thread-safe
> initialization behavior of versions of Visual Studio prior to Visual
> Studio 2015, use the /Zc:threadSafeInit- option. If you know that
> thread-safety is not required, use this option to generate slightly
> smaller, faster code around static local declarations.
>
> Thread-safe static local variables use thread-local storage (TLS)
> internally to provide efficient execution when the static has already
> been initialized. The implementation of this feature relies on Windows
> operating system support functions in Windows Vista and later
> operating systems. Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and older
> operating systems do not have this support, so they do not get the
> efficiency advantage. These operating systems also have a lower limit
> on the number of TLS sections that can be loaded. Exceeding the TLS
> section limit can cause a crash. If this is a problem in your code,
> especially in code that must run on older operating systems, use
> /Zc:threadSafeInit- to disable the thread-safe initialization code.